# Rear wheel resistance and vibrations are driving me crazy

Tags: fixed-gear, rear-wheel

I've recently purchased a new wheel set for my track bike. It's a Phil Wood High Flange laced to H + Son Archetype.

I've been traveling a bit and haven't really ridden them very long. I immediately set them up on my bike and rode them the following day on a 40 mile ride. Halfway through through my ride I started feeling a bit of resistance, as if someone was holding me back, causing me to use use more energy and slowing me down.

I pulled off, checked chain tension, alignment and wheel rub (no brake rub because I ride brakeless) but everything was fine. I've read on here of similar scenarios from other riders however, many said they were going a particular speed. Somewhere between 20-30mph. Mine is on and off, the resistance does pick up on elevated speeds but for the most part it holds me back.

Today I went for a ride, looked over the rear wheel especially and again, everything checked out totally fine. Though, it went straight into the same issues as before. Only on my way home my rear wheel actually somehow loosened and had major wheel rub. I pulled over and realigned the wheel and tightened. It didn't happen again.

If anyone can give some suggestions or opinions I'll really appreciate it. Cheers

Comment: Can you replicate resistance with the bike stationary and held off of the ground?

Comment: Do you have access to rollers for diagnosis ?

Comment: Argenti Apparatus: Good question, I forgot to mention, while I was checking the bike on my rides, I cannot create the resistance while the rear of the bike is off the ground.

Comment: Criggie: Unfortunately no :( Very sad about that.

Comment: You're sure the new tire isn't slightly larger, causing it to rub the frame?  Might only happen when the frame is flexed from your weight.

Comment: Are these sealed? I would check if the bearings are properly seated in the cups. Also I'd dissasemble it and check inside if there is a bearing spacer(just like in a BMX bottom bracket) so it can be pinched as it should by the bearings, meaning less roll resistance

Comment: Daniel R Hicks: I’m riding a 23cm on it.

Comment: dmb: good point I’ll double check. Hope they would be, considering it’s all new.

Comment: Consider putting some tape on possible wear spots - chainstay/tyre is likely.  Ride a bit then check for witness marks on the tape.   The problem is only showing up while riding, so its got to be a dynamic thing caused by riding.  Flex is my guess - you might need to drop to smaller tyres.... remember this is a track bike, not intended for comfort nor the road.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the bearings are worn. I know its new but it's worth checking. If there's no grease on the bearings, apply some grease on the bearings and install the wheel back. But before doing that, check if the bearings were screwed in too tight. if that doesn't make any sense to you, I apologize.